# jQuery.bind() events on plain Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it ok to bind jQuery events to plain, non-DOM Javascript objects:

```
var myobject = {};
$(myobject).bind("foobar", function() { alert("daa"); });

$(myobject).trigger("foobar");
```

What are the implications for

- Garbage collection (no new references created preventing object to GC'ed)
- Object attributes (new attributes assigned to the object)?
- Performance

Some things I have noted

- Event name must not conflict with a function name on the object, e.g. you cannot have function init and event named init and trigger it correclty

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: If you wanted an event system, I'd suggest creating your own, or using an existing one that is meant for typical JS objects. They're not hard to write, and it will be more specific to what you want to do.

Comment: i can't think of a good reason to do this.

Comment: One reason is to implement super simple event emitter: https://gist.github.com/1032342

Comment: Why would I write my own event system if I could use jQuery event system?

Comment: I would use a Class rather than an object and give it some methods, such as addEvent, trigger, and removeEvent, and use the new jQuery.Callbacks method to handle the events. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/

Comment: Works nice, including jQuery 3.5 but with notice: if plain object has method `foobar`, it will be triggered too. Actually its better to use triggerHandler instead of trigger: `$(myobject).triggerHandler("foobar");`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using the jquery event system, I would implement one that mimics it using the [jQuery.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/) method.

```
var myClass = function(){
    this._callbacks = {};
};
myClass.prototype = {
  addEvent: function(evname,callback) {
    if (!this._callbacks[evname]) {
      this._callbacks[evname] = $.Callbacks();
    }
    this._callbacks[evname].add(callback);
  },
  removeEvent: function(evname) {
    if (!this._callbacks[evname]) {
      return;
    }
    this._callbacks[evname].remove();
    //Might need this too:
    //this._callbacks[evname] = null;
  },
  triggerEvent: function(evname) {
    if (this._callbacks[evname]) {
      this._callbacks[evname].fire();
    }
  }
};
var foo = new myClass();
foo.addEvent("foo",function(){
  console.log('foo');
});
foo.triggerEvent("foo");
foo.removeEvent("foo");
// event was removed, the below line won't do anything.
foo.triggerEvent("foo");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEuAP/

---

However, to answer your question, I don't see any immediate problems with what you are doing other than it isn't documented and may change functionality from version to version (although it works in all currently available versions 1.2.6+).

Comment: Thanks. Callbacks objects was new for me and probably the most suitable way to do this, using helper function callbackify(object)

Comment: I nonetheless still fail to understand why I'd implement my own.

Comment: @Quickredfox Maybe because the jQuery event system isn't meant for plain objects? Just because it works now doesn't mean it will work later.

Comment: It WILL work later. The man himself says so http://forum.jquery.com/topic/triggering-custom-events-on-js-objects
 :)

Comment: This just frankly does not answer the question and if the functionality already exist, re-inventing hot water is just code bloat...

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as jQuery support alteration of object properties via animate also, this is definitely fine.

```
var obj = {'test':0}; 
var interval = setInterval(function(){console.log(obj);}, 250);
$(obj).on("fun", function(){this.test++});

$(obj).animate(
    {'test':100}, 
    3000, 
    function (){ 
        console.log(obj);
        clearInterval(interval);


        $(obj).trigger("fun")
        console.log("increment",obj); 
    }
);

//will console log {test: 1.5}, {test: 6.4} etc then {test: 100}
//and finally "interval" {test: 101}
```

Quickredfox's backup comment is a pretty good source too:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/triggering-custom-events-on-js-objects