# what is the pitfall in using jquery on/off and trigger method on non-dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a potential pitfall in using jquery on/off method and trigger to execute on non-dom elements/regular js objects.

thanks

Comment: Please provide concrete examples.

Comment: Also wondering if there a better solution than going with jquery for observable pattern/bind & trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use `.on` and `.off` on regular objects, as long as you keep in mind that it will add additional properties to the object.

```
var obj = {};

$(obj).on("mycustomevent",function(){
  alert("mycustomevent triggered");
  $(this).off("mycustomevent").trigger("mycustomevent");
}).trigger("mycustomevent"); // fires off one alert.
```

I must ask though, in what situation does it make sense to bind events to an object? why not just give the object a method that you can call?

Comment: it is bind and trigger situation

Comment: Right, but you could give the object methods, such as obj.addEvent(name,callback) or obj.on(name,callback) and then give the object another method called trigger that triggers the given event name. The new `$.Callbacks()` method of jQuery would be a big help in that kind of setup.

Comment: Here's an answer i posted recently with an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099555/jquery-bind-events-on-plain-javascript-objects/9101404#9101404 In that answer i'm using a class, but it could just as easily be implemented on an object.